# Update specific row of table of multiple entries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I have a table of customers. Each customer has a first and a last name. The two text fields of the table are editable. So users can update the information when they press Save. The problem is that I cannot get the specific row information,I only get the first row results

I tried to match to the names with the input field but I had no success.

```
<?php foreach($customer as $each){ ?>
    <td class="first_name" id="first" contenteditable="true"><?php echo 
    $each['first_name']; ?></td>
    <td class="last_name" id="last"  contenteditable="true"><?php echo 
    $each['last_name']; ?></td>
    <td >   <button type="button" onclick="save('<?php echo $each['first_name'];? 
    >','<?php echo $each['last_name'];?>');" >Save</button></td>
    <? } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function save(first,second) {
      <?php foreach($customer as $each){?>
        var first_name = "<?php echo $each['first_name']?>";
        var last_name = "<?php echo $each['last_name']?>";
        if (first_name==first && last_name == second){
          var fname = document.querySelectorAll(".first_name");
          console.log(fname[0]);
        }
        <?php } ?>

      }
 </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: That because when you doing `this.document.querySelector('#first_name'),` you always get the first name. You should look for / save the name you got in the argument of the function

Comment: It is because you use IDs. IDs are unique, so you can only use them once in the document. You should use the class-attribute to achieve this.

Comment: Try using classes instead of id's `.first-name` `.last-name`

Comment: @AndrejsGubars I edited the code and added the classes plus added the querySelectorAl. Still, I am getting only the first row results

Comment: yes, because `this.document.querySelector('.className')` will return the first occurrence. use `this.document.querySelectorAll('.className')` will return you an array of all elements with that `className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a different query selector. Assign a classname or an attribute to the elements you want to select (e.g `name` for querying with `.name`) then `querySelectorAll` method will return an array of the elements that matched your query.

Comment: I have edited my code. Still, with classes and querySelectorAll, I get only the first result

Comment: you specifically used the first one: `console.log(fname[0]);` if you need them all use a `for...in` loop or something similar

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that I see is that you create unnecessary `foreach` loop inside a `javascript` function using `php`.

You can dynamically create your table and the contents inside it, that's fine. But the javascript does not care about that and you should not create javascript with php. So I would do it this way.

I wrap the td's in tr's cause i'm assuming you are putting that data in tr.

```php
<?php foreach($customer as $each){ ?>
  <tr class="customer-row">
    <td class="first_name" contenteditable="true"><?php echo 
    $each['first_name']; ?></td>
    <td class="last_name" contenteditable="true"><?php echo 
    $each['last_name']; ?></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
<? } ?>
```

Then outside the php foreach loop i would create my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var saveBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".save");

for(var i = 0; i < saveBtn.length; i++) {
  // attach click event to every button.
  saveBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var _this = this;
    var _tr = _this.closest(".customer-row");
    var fname = _tr.querySelector(".first_name").innerText;
    var lname = _tr.querySelector(".last_name").innerText;
    console.log("Name: ", fname + " " + lname");
    // below you can implement your check name logic...
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm not 100% sure if my js will not throw errors, but it should give you an indication that you should separate your `server-side` from `client-side` logic.